# Cannot Find MVC 3 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a new MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010. However when selecting new project I cannot see MVC 3 in my list of installed templates. I have the option set to .NET Framework 4 and it still does not appear. Do I need to download some dependency somewhere or am I missing a simple step?

Comment: try installing http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: @vgSefa The right link for version 3 is this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3